# Customize default current location alert message (iOS)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, location

Is it possible to customize the default alert message when the iPhone wants to use users current location. I want to change not only the text but also the default blue screen alert view. Is it possible ?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not possible. From [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125),

> Important: In addition to hardware not being available, the user has
>   the option of denying an application’s access to location service
>   data. During its initial uses by an application, the Core Location
>   framework prompts the user to confirm that using the location service
>   is acceptable. If the user denies the request, the CLLocationManager
>   object reports an appropriate error to its delegate during future
>   requests. You can also check the application’s explicit authorization
>   status using the authorizationStatus method.

The alert is prompted by Core location framework. We don't have any control over it.

EDIT : To add up, from [this](https://devforums.apple.com/message/181980#181980) Apple developer forum thread (login required)

> That alert is shown in a standard fashion for all applications for
>   privacy reasons.  The user's current location is sensitive
>   information, and we want to be sure that they give their informed
>   consent to any use of it on the device.  The way that we do that is by
>   providing a clear, consistent mechanism for the user to give their
>   consent.  If applications were allowed to **override** or disable the
>   alert, then that consistency would be lost.

and the answerer is an Apple employee..

Answer (score 2):

Years later, Apple did implement some customization options!

Have a look at the documentation
[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)

If you put one of the following key in your info.plist (depending on your usage of the location services), you can specify a custom string, that is displayed in the default alert additionally.

- NSLocationUsageDescription (available since iOS6)
- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription (since iOS8)
- NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription (since iOS8)